# How do i implement nested foreach with data from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I have a process table which lists all processes. it has a primary key of processid. it has a column for cateforyid which contains the categoryid of the process. I have a separate category table which has a categoryid and category name.

[image: process table]   [image: category table]  [image]

From my controller, I get all processes from my model and a separate function to get all categories.

Then in my view, i have this code:

```
<?php
    foreach ($category as $c) {
        echo "<li>" . $c->CategoryName . "</li>";
        foreach ($process as $r) {
            if ($r->CategoryID == $c->CategoryID) {
                echo "<ul>";
                echo "<li>" . anchor("process/id/$r->ProcessID", $r->ProcessName, 'target="_blank"') .  "</li>";
                echo "</ul>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

It works fine but it lists the categories even if they dont have any processes under them. How can i implement in such a way that it only lists the categories if there is a process under them?

Comment: Can you explain it with an example.

Comment: Why is your Process model returning categories that have no processes?

Comment: What is the correct SQL command to retrieve all processes with their process.processid, process.processname and categoryname for a certain country. Currently i use `SELECT process.ProcessID, process.ProcessName, process.CategoryID, category.CategoryName
FrOM process, category
JOIN process_country
ON process_country.ProcessID = process.ProcessID
WHERE process_country.CountryCode = 'AM'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use explicit `JOIN`s for your `SELECT` statements. **Never** just list tables in the `FROM` clause. You're also missing `JOIN` criteria for your `Category` table. Instead, try:

```
SELECT
    P.ProcessID,
    P.ProcessName,
    P.CategoryID,
    CAT.CategoryName
FROM
    Process P
INNER JOIN Category CAT ON CAT.CategoryID = P.CategoryID
INNER JOIN Process_Country PC ON
    PC.ProcessID = P.ProcessID AND
    PC.CountryCode = 'AM'
```

Comment: just a followup question, is the one table sufficient to list in my view Categories and Processes under each category?

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking, but if you have another question then you're probably better off opening it as a new question rather than try to discuss it in comments. That will help others with the same problem find it in the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

Place a condition with `ProcessName` is not empty:

```
<?php
    foreach ($category as $c) {
        echo "<li>" . $c->CategoryName . "</li>";
        foreach ($process as $r) {
            if ($r->CategoryID == $c->CategoryID && isset($r->ProcessName) && strlen(trim($r->ProcessName)) > 0) {
                echo "<ul>";
                echo "<li>" . anchor("process/id/$r->ProcessID", $r->ProcessName, 'target="_blank"') .  "</li>";
                echo "</ul>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Note: You can use !empty() as well.